# Joomla plugin to display github code into articles

Tags: joomla, github, embed, code-view

Is there any plugin available for joomla 2.5 to embed code from github repository. For word press there is a plugin to achieve the same (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/github-code-viewer-2/). I wanted to do include code from my github repository into my joomla/k2 articles using something like

```
{github url='https://github.com/jamescarr/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/filters/AbstractFileListFilter.java'}
```

By looking at the wp plugin I thought of writing my own joomla plugin but WP plugin is using ***wp_remote_fopen*** function and i did not find the same kind of function in joomla and read some articles about vulnerabilities using such remote_open functions. Here is what WP plugin is doing

```
function getGitHubFile($url, $ttl = null){
        self::__loadCache($url, $ttl);

        if (isset(self::$cache[$url])) {
            $code = self::$cache[$url];
        } else {
            $code = wp_remote_fopen($url . '?raw=true');
            if ($code == '') {
                return 'You need cURL installed to use GitHub_Code_Viewer';
            }
            $code = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $code);
            self::__setCache($url, $code);
        }

        return $code;
    }
```

Comment: The wp_remote_fopen method of Wordpress would be equivalent to using cURL in Joomla. Look at the php.net for info about how to use this. If cURL is disabled on the server, then try with fopen() or file_get_contents();

Comment: Do we have any joomla api for the same instead of using php api?

Comment: Not that I know of. The JFile classes are for local files only.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: I've fixed the problems mentioned below &** [published a new plugin on github for Joomla 2.5 & 3.0](https://github.com/itoffshore/plg_githubrepo/releases) - the plugin author should be updating [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-display/github-repo) soon.

---

<del>There is a [Github Repo](http://www.escope.cz/en/extensions/github-repo/github-repo-documentation) plugin for **Joomla 2.5** which uses the `repojs` mentioned by @Jean-Marie Favre.</del>

To get this working on **Joomla 3** you need to edit `githubrepo.php` & change:

```
   if ( version_compare( JVERSION, '3.0', '<' ) == 1) { 
        if($jquery){
                $document->addScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');
        }
   } else {
        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
   }
```

To just `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

Depending on your server setup you may also see the following errors in `firebug`:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://raw.github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js/master/fonts/repo.woff.
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://raw.github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js/master/fonts/repo.ttf.
```

[Enabling Cross Domain Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header/5009126#5009126) did not work for me so I fixed these by uploading all the fonts in [repo.js](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js) to my webserver & editing the 4 paths in `repo.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a try with http://darcyclarke.me/dev/repojs/
I've managed to include it in a joomla article (by including the javascript code directly in the page) so that one can browse a github repository from within a joomla article.