# toolbar icons are not being displayed in tinymce (4.0.1) text editor

Tags: tinymce

I'm upgrading tinyMCE from 3.4.2 to 4.0.1. Everything works perfect locally. But problem started when I published everything at server. Toolbar loads fine but the icons are not showing properly. Note: I have separate projects for app and CDN. I'm guessing this is a cross-domain/url reference issue but unable to figure it out. Currently the toolbar is loading as shown in the - [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/tWqQmsznFUs/)!

```
    tinyMCE.init({
// General options
theme: "modern",
editor_selector: "mceDesignerEditorAutoresize",
relative_urls: false,
convert_urls: false,
toolbar1: "cut copy paste | bold italic | undo redo | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | link unlink image code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor | imgCustom attachCustom",
toolbar_items_size: 'small',
plugins:  [
    "autoresize advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor"
],   
accessibility_warnings: false,
accessibility_focus: false,
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.addButton('imgCustom', {
        title: 'Image',
        image: $("#jsTinyMCEImageUrl").val().toString(),
        onclick: function () {
            openModalPopup($("#jsTinyMCEImagePath").val(), "width=700,height=600");
        }
    });
    ed.addButton('attachCustom', {
        title: 'Attachment',
        image: $("#jsTinyMCEAttachUrl").val().toString(),
        onclick: function () {
            try {
                openModalPopup($("#jsTinyMCEAttachPath").val(), "width=400,height=200");
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
    });
},
language: $('#TinyMCECurrentLanguage').val(),
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true
```

});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is found that /js/tinymce/skin/lightgray/fonts folder was not being copied to server. This happened as Visual Studio didn't recognize the font files and marked them as 'None' in Build Action and as a result these files were not being published.

Solved it by right clicking the font files, select Properties and Set value for Build Action to 'Content'.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add some further information to this question, for people who come along later. I experienced exactly the same problem, but in my case it was to do with cross-site font loading in Firefox. (Perhaps you will still have the problem if you test in Firefox)

Anyway the solution is to allow cross-site loading of fonts with the following http header on the site that the TinyMCE code is being loaded from:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Full details of how to do this can be found at [How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header)