# Configure Brackets Server to avoid Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors

Tags: jquery, adobe-brackets

In my code, I'm fetching some JSON from another server of a different domain with a jQuery, and get an error in the browser.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url_containing_json.com. Origin http://localhost:53651  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Is it easy to configure the Brackets server to allow this?  Or do I need to set up my own server to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This restriction comes from the web browser, not the server. It's called the [same-origin security policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (aka the same-domain policy).

What is the `http://url_containing_json.com` "JSON server" in question? Is it a server you have some control over? If so, then you can either:

A) Upload your code to the "JSON server" itself so your site is served from that same domain; or

B) Upload your code to some other staging server, and use [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) on the JSON server to essentially whitelist the staging server's domain name (the JSON server would provide an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header, as mentioned in the error message).

On the other hand -- if the "JSON server" is completely third-party, does it actually *want* other sites like yours to be fetching its JSON? If so, then it should already support either CORS (with a blanket allow-all policy) or [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) (an older way of allowing access, though your requests will need to be set up a little differently).

If the JSON server *doesn't* permit cross-domain requests, you have one last resort: use your own site's server as a proxy. Instead of your page pinging the JSON server directly, your page pings its own server, which then pings the JSON server on the page's behalf.

All these approaches require running your own server instead of using the built-in Brackets "localhost" server. You can point Brackets at your own server via *File > Project Settings...*, but be aware that will disable certain features like Live HTML Development. (Though if you're able to use option "B" above you could maybe hack your `hosts` file to keep using the built-in Brackets server instead by changing its apparent domain).

Hope that helps!

Comment: So, in researching this question before I posted, it seems like it's a matter of adding a header via the server, like the link below, and therefore I figure there is some way to do that with the internal server in Brackets, but I can't figure out how to access it or where it lives. The whole point of using Brackets to me is the Live Preview feature, so it would be nice to know how to configure it's internal server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: Unfortunately it's the other way around - you need to add a header to the server _you're contacting_. The "JSON server" in this case. If you don't control that server and it doesn't want to give you access (i.e. it doesn't provide that header nor a JSONP-based API) then your options are pretty limited. That's true even in production.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what the server is that you're trying to contact?

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into the exact same problem. The way I got around this was to use a jsonp ajax request type, using the dataType parameter of the $.ajax() call.
See the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on this call.