# jQuery not working for load

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the First File I wanna load This works in div that has id="main"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="menu" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:2%;right:0;left:0;">
        <a href="#" id="target"> Link </a>
    </div>
    <div id="main" style="position:absolute;top:20%;left:20%;right:20%;left:20%;">
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#target").click(function(){
                $("#main").load("target.html");
            });
        });     
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Second file contains only this info

```
<h1 style="text-align:center"> This Worked </h1>
```

Under Network tab

[image]

Comment: Are the files in the same folder ?

Comment: Well both are on the desktop(Windows 8.1) I used chrome IE and firefox no result

Comment: You are using a webserver, or are you just running this from a file:// protocol ?

Comment: I am running this from file

Comment: @adeneo I have WAMP installed on this machine.So does it affect the file?

Comment: Are you running this in WAMP, as localhost etc.

Comment: No I exit WAMP sometime back

Comment: So rigth now you're just opening the files from the desktop straight into the browser? If so, you need to use a webserver, like WAMP, otherwise ajax requests won't work.

Comment: :) it worked thanks a ton ! i`m so sorry for wasting so much of your time please post your comment as an answer so that in the near future dumb people like me can get enlightened

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure target.html path is correct, "target.html"

```
 $("#main").load("<...path...>/target.html");
```

Comment: both are on desktop so what path should I give? ./target.html or something else

Comment: If you are in same folder don't want change path.

Comment: could you please copy 2 files to a folder, and check it

Comment: Moved it to D:/test/target.html changed the load to given path still no luck

Comment: I have created two files from source and copied to one folder. Here it is working perfectly.

Comment: can you post code which browser and operating system are you using?

Comment: I have using Mozilla and OS is Windows 7

Comment: :( No luck for me am doing something wrong the code I have posted is the exact same in my 2 html files but it just isn`t working for me

Comment: do you have any FTP account ? Please upload it and check it. After please give that URL

Comment: I don`t have any FTP account when I do inspect element i get the below result

Comment: Please try this code then error will display, 
        $( "#main" ).load( "target.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    alert( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});

Comment: Replace that line with this $( "#main" ).load( "target.html", function( response, status, xhr ) { if ( status == "error" ) { var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: "; alert( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText ); } });

Comment: Your code should work in live server.I have checked it in local and live.

Answer (score 0):

What does say your Chrome (or FF) inspector ? Look in the network tab, if the target.html file is correctly loaded.

Comment: when i click inspect element->network under Name jqery.min.map Method GET status 304

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, just check target.html page you have added contains html, body tags as you may have missed for demo. After checking they are in same folder..

Comment: <html>
<body>
zhdfijhzug s ghu hd
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue. It seems you are testing on Chrome.

So, This will not work on chrome locally because of this error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, Please upload to a live server or test it with mozilla firefox.

After Clicking the link, Open Console tab to view the error.

**There is no issue in your Code**

Answer (score 0):

Your script issue a security warning :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load target.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Your problem is related to this thread, take a look to understand : 
[How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header)
You have to explictly declare that you are allowed to request this resource.