# XMLHttpRequest cannot load - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

**ERROR XMLHttpRequest cannot load - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

```
//XMLHttpRequest

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (!('withCredentials' in xhr)) { 
alert('Browser does not support CORS.'); 
return; 
} 
xhr.onerror = function() { 
alert('There was an error.'); 
}; 
xhr.onload = function() {"done"}
xhr.open("GET", "http://indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx/ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicos?tcIndicador=318&tcFechaInicio=01/03/2014&tcFechaFinal=01/01/2016&tcNombre=A&tnSubNiveles=N",true);
xhr.send(null);
console.log("loading >>>")
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header

Comment: Stackoverflow is a **Q** and A site. You forgot about `Q`.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of your question, the answer is:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Exactly as described in the error.

This means that at the server, you need to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response that indicates to the browser that the current domain is permitted to download from this host. If the server in question is out of your control, then you're out of luck and you'll need to download the content server-side.

Comment: Or, to put it simpler. JFGI

Comment: In development to overcome you can make use of plugin called CORS in the browser.

Comment: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." how exactly to do it?