# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9001/Strategy.svc/NewStrategy

Tags: c#, http

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9001/Strategy.svc/NewStrategy. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:9000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you trying to host the application in IIS??

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header value to 'http://localhost:9000' but the origin hold's value "http://localhost:4200".

Modify such that both of them match.

Please find similar problem with solutions

[XMLHttpRequest cannot load - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021391/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059658/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-o/20059813)

Comment: in case of problem is not solved give us some code to work with