# CSS - dashed color font

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to show the text on webpage which looks like:

[image]

The font has two alternate colors. Is it even possible? The solution should work for all the browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dotted text in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140013/dotted-text-in-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you have proper font file that can be included in your page.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(dashed_font.woff);
}
```

Comment: You mean I need to develop a custom font for the same, where my graphics team will have to create each character in SVG for all the ascii characters atleast

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that an `eot` font would also be needed for some versions of Internet Explorer.  Also this solution won't work if two colours are needed, both different to the background colour.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done natively in CSS without using a custom font in Google Chrome and other WebKit browsers using `-webkit-background-clip`.

```css
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        135deg,
        #3f3f3f,
        #3f3f3f 2px,
        #7f7f7f 2px,
        #7f7f7f 4px
    );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Your text here</h1>
```

Note that this will just display as text in front of a rectangular stripy background in other browsers such as Firefox or IE.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) explains `-webkit-background-clip` and a few fallbacks for other browsers.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/) explains making striped backgrounds in plain CSS3.

Comment: Thanks but chrome is not enough. It should work in all the browsers

Comment: This is **working** in Firefox Nightly because FireFox will support `-webkit` prefixes!