# My ajax cross-domain request getting cancelled by Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm making these ajax requests from a Google Chrome extension which I'm trying to create, but every time my extension makes a request it gets cancelled. I don't know why.

This snippet below works fine.

```
    function makeRequest(method, url){
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("GET", "http://www.djjohal.com");
         xhr.send();
      }


      setTimeout(makeRequest, 10000)
```

But when I change the above code to this, it didn't work.

```
    var submit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]')
    submit.addEventListener('click', callback)


    function makeRequest(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.send();
    }


    function callback(){
        makeRequest('GET', 'http://www.djjohal.com')
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you run the 2nd code from a different domain?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Extensions are restricted from making cross-site requests unless the Extension has the correct security permission.

See Also: [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr) on the Chrome Developer site.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a setting on the djjohal.com server.

Trying both snippets of code given in the question, I receive this message from Chrome in a normal webpage:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.djjohal.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

[How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header)

If you aren't in control of djjohal, you aren't doing anything wrong.

Comment: try to run in the extension first Snippet works fine.but second one fail.