# Same-origin policy

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy, access-control

I'm getting this error while calling javascipt:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://sub.domain.com/actions/action1.php.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

- Javascript is placed here: `https://www.domain.com/page.php`
- Javascript do job through: `https://sub.domain.com/actions/action1.php` (requested resource)

I have found the easiest way how to solve this problem (same-origin policy):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.domain = 'domain.com';
</script>
```

But this isn't solving my problem. I have also tried to add this piece of code to both pages, but still nothing.

Any simple suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: [Enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) in the ``domain.com`` or you need to proxy all the XHR request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the error, you will need to [add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header) to the headers of the response, or use a different method such as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This is a JavaScript security feature to prevent cross site scripting and cannot be circumvented.

Comment: Thank you, this code in .htaccess solved my problem - `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{HTTP_ORIGIN}e" env=HTTP_ORIGIN`

Comment: But I would like to know if it is necessary to add this code only in .htaccess placed in subdomain folder, in main folder, or both?