# .NET equivalent of .htaccess file

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, cors, font-awesome

I am trying to enable CORS in .NET to get round Firefox policy on cross-domain resources (fontawesome in my case).

I've found this [solution for Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header) that I want to translate to .NET.

I've tried to follow [these guidelines](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) for the translation, but I got stuck.

This is the relevant bit I want to translate from the `.htaccess` file to my `web.config` file.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CORS:

- Globally? In `web.config`:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  ```
- More control: 
  [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

---

### MIME

Though unsure about your sample above - they're font files? If so, could it just be `MIME` mapping in IIS (not CORS)?

```
<system.webServer>
     <staticContent>        
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        ...
    </staticContent>  
</system.webServer>
```

Hth...