# Slider Revolution custom font display

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face, revolution-slider

I am trying to embed a custom font into a slide and not so sure why, it doesn't display correctly.

I've followed all these [instructions](http://www.themepunch.com/faq/use-fonts-google-fonts/), uploading the font kit on the server, modifying the url's, applying the `css` settings to `custom css` slider rev. field, calling the font type `font-family: itsadzokeregular;` into the Advance editor section but something is missing; the result is the same no matter what browser I'll use to open [this](http://goo.gl/urOSTM) page.

Can I have your support please, what did I do wrong?
Thank you,

Comment: as you can see from the inspector, there is a CORS issue (Cross-origin authentication) and the fonts are locked. Did you copy the fonts on your server? and also, that is the font you want to use?

Comment: what is exactly the error?

Comment: is the font working fine now?

Comment: Thank you for your feed-back, I have used Ash's answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header/5009126#5009126) and it looks like it's working. In the first phase, I've still received an error using www mydomain dot com instead of mydomain dot com in the font referral links but after editing having the same address form as I've used in the .htaccess file, it's working like a charm as I said :) thank you all .