# How can i use Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want every site to be able to use XMLHttpRequests to read the content of files in my website. So i heard about something called "Access-Control-Allow-Origin
", How can i use it?

Comment: What have you found googling it/searching on StackOverflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008944/how-to-add-an-access-control-allow-origin-header)